# When an insights metric says "clicked anywhere," what exactly does "anywhere" mean?

Tags: metrics, facebook-insights

The "Page Post: Engagement" metrics mention that they report the number of times people "click anywhere" in your posts, which leaves me wondering if this means the number of times links in your posts are clicked on, or does it also track the number of times any click is registered on any white space, image, text, etc. within a post?

Essentially: how is engagement through clicking "anywhere" defined by Facebook?

For reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#post_engagement

Comment: Offtopic. try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic for StackOverflow. You may want to contact facebook and ask.

Answer (score 0):

It means any link included in your page post. Any link inside your post, opening a photo, ... Or any "meta" link generated by Facebook and included in your post: "Like", "Share", "Report", ...

Basically: anything that can be clicked in your post and that will lead to an action.